# APK Crash when installing from Google Play but not from eclipse/apk file

Tags: android, android-manifest, runtimeexception

I released a new version of one of my apps and I start getting tons of errors from users about crashing issues when the application start.

These are the errors I'm getting:

First error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.jayColber.andcarryon/com.jayColber.andcarryon.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jayColber.andcarryon.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.jayColber.andcarryon-1.apk]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jayColber.andcarryon.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.jayColber.andcarryon-1.apk]
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
... 11 more
```

Second error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.jayColber.andcarryon/com.jayColber.andcarryon.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jayColber.andcarryon.MainActivity
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jayColber.andcarryon.MainActivity
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1039)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
... 11 more
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jayColber.andcarryon"
    android:versionCode="10"
    android:versionName="1.1.3"  >
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>   
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.motorola.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.motorola.dlauncher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.fede.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.lge.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="org.adw.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.motorola.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.motorola.dlauncher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.lge.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon144" 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:allowBackup="true" 
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity" android:label="Keep Calm" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="BackgroundSelector" android:label="Select Background" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
        <activity android:name="library.AmbilWarna" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
        <activity android:name="IconSelector" android:label="Select Icon" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
        <activity android:name="ShareSelector" android:label="Share your poster" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
        <activity android:name="colorSelector" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
        <activity android:name="infoActivity" android:label="Info" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.revmob.ads.fullscreen.FullscreenActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
       <activity android:name="com.apperhand.device.android.EULAActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.apperhand.device.android.AndroidSDKProvider"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.startapp.android.DEV_ID" android:value="1011042240"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.startapp.android.APP_ID" android:value="201812008"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I tried installing the application in several devices with APK file & TestFlight and it worked perfectly - but when installing in devices from Google Play it crashes immediately.

Comment: I advice you do unpublish the current release & revert back to old one until the issue is solved. You are losing your loyal users.

Comment: Is the APK you used for testing, same as the one you submitted to Google? Also, are both testing and submitting APK signed with the same key?

Answer (score 0):

The correct shorthand if you are not specifying the package name for each of your components is to start it with a period.  E.g. instead of

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity" android:label="Keep Calm" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
```

it should be:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="Keep Calm" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
```

Likewise for all your other components.  Otherwise you should specify the package name

```
<activity android:name="com.jayColber.andcarryon.MainActivity" android:label="Keep Calm" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
```

Comment: It need not like the one, you are mentioning,
 All the three above are same. It will work fine. There is something else causing the issue

Comment: @VenomVendor What I say is correct according to the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) in the section "Declaring class names", it says "The name must include the full package designation".  So, the manifest is incorrect in this respect although it may not be the only problem.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but the user is asking for solution of the crash, not the documentation part.

Comment: Well that could be related to the crash as if you have errors in your manifest it could lead to undefined behaviour. The manifest is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer although i believe this is not the problem (i changed it like you say it should be). B.T.W - it worked fine with the same manifest declaration.